# Writing Forecasting Model data to Oracle DB

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

So i have a forecasting model built in python that generate prediction of people planning strategy for future months. I am facing problem writing the data to oracle table. i get the below error

`sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1044: value cannot be represented as an Oracle number`

Code that writes the forecasted output to oracle Schema

```
transfer_in_full.rename(columns={'Date':'ds','Predicted_ARIMA':'predicted_arima','Predicted_UCM':'predicted_ucm','ARIMA error':'arima_error','UCM_error':'ucm_error','Prophet_error':'prophet_error','lowestError':'lowesterror','Count':'count'},inplace=True)
transfer_out_full.rename(columns={'Date':'ds','Predicted_ARIMA':'predicted_arima','Predicted_UCM':'predicted_ucm','ARIMA error':'arima_error','UCM_error':'ucm_error','Prophet_error':'prophet_error','lowestError':'lowesterror','Count':'count'},inplace=True)

trunc_query = "truncate table HIM_PA_EXTERN_PROD.TRANSFER_IN_FORECAST"
engine.execute(trunc_query)

transfer_in_full['predicted_arima'] = np.where(transfer_in_full['predicted_arima'] < 0,0,transfer_in_full['predicted_arima'])
# trf_in_col.to_excel('transfer_in_trend.xlsx')

trf_in_col = pd.read_sql("select * from HIM_PA_EXTERN_PROD.TRANSFER_IN_FORECAST", engine).columns.tolist()
transfer_in_full = transfer_in_full[trf_in_col]

dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(transfer_in_full[c].str.len().max()) for c in transfer_in_full.columns[transfer_in_full.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
transfer_in_full.to_sql('TRANSFER_IN_FORECAST', engine, if_exists='append', index=False,schema='HIM_PA_EXTERN_PROD',dtype=dtyp)
```

I understand it can due to data type mismatch as the farecasting output values can be blank as well scientific(1.91644748735735E-30). Is there a way i can handle the data format from forecasting model

Comment: Please [edit] the question including a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for your table(s); a minimal example of the python code you are using; the input you are giving to the python code. If you don't give a [MRE] then we have to guess what is making your error and you will get fewer answers (if any) or inappropriate guesses.

Comment: @MT0, I have added the code that writes the data from python to oracle and how the forecasted output is trimmed

Comment: I agree you should update with a runnable example as previously requested.  If you can't do that, then can you update your question with the data value you are using, the table definition, the versions of sqlalchemy, cx_Oracle, Oracle Client libraries, and Oracle DB?